# Youngest file in folder

Tags: r

I am looking for the date of the youngest file in a folder. However, it is a big folder (+14 000 files) so I want to do it efficiently. So far I came up with the following code:

```
folder <- 'my/folder/path'
max(file.info(paste(folder,dir(folder),sep='/'))$mtime)
```

Unfortunately this takes ages (this makes sense since he has to go and ask each file for its last modification date). Is there a way to apply this operation on the whole folder at once in the same way that dir() works? I assume it should be possible because sorting by date in windows explorer takes less than one second.

Comment: How much time did it take? I don't see any obvious way to speed up things considerably. However, instead of `paste`, just use `dir(...,full.names=TRUE)` that gives you the full path and not just the file name. Maybe it's the `paste` part that it's taking some time. If that's not enough, consider calling `ls` through `system` (if you are under Linux).

Comment: About 7 seconds per 100 files

Comment: This is pretty strange, since as for @fdetsch answer, I tested your code and it takes less than a second for 1000+files folder. 7 seconds for 100 files is huge. Maybe your filesystem is severely fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, there are +1,500 files in the folder I used for testing and the below solution takes less than 0.1s to perform. Have a try!

```
## list files in current working directory
fls <- list.files()

## extract file with latest modification date
system.time({
  fls_info <- file.info(fls)
  fls_info[which.max(fls_info$mtime), ]
})

>   user  system elapsed 
>  0.010   0.017   0.073
```

Comment: Hmm, do you have an SSD? On my computer it is comparable to the other script. I also made the mistake to first run list.files without the full paths and then it was super fast since the files do not exist. However, in that case it does not return anything useful.

Comment: I set the working directory to the folder containing the data, so `full.names = TRUE` was not required in this particular case. I'm indeed working with an SSD which might contribute to a better performance. Haven't thought of that...

Comment: I checked on a smaller dataset and your script takes 3.07s while the old took 3.15s. I think the main constraint here is the disk speed then :-)